# Setting a List to empty if it is null

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to combine two lists, either one of these lists can be null. I understand that you should not be working with null lists, so I am trying to set them to an empty list before I combine them. The problem is, I can only seem to check if the second list is null when I am trying to concat, see below!

```
List<AccountAlert> xAccountEmails = new List<AccountAlert>();
List<AccountAlert> xAccountPhones = new List<AccountAlert>();
///Lots of things happen

//Below throws a compiler error cannot implicity convert IEnumerable to Generic.List
xAccountEmails = xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop").ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<AccountAlert>();
// Below throws the same compiler error
xAccountEmails = xAccountEmails ?? Enumerable.Empty<AccountAlert>();
//Below works!
xAccountPhones = xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop").ToList();
xAccountCombined = xAccountEmails.Concat(xAccountPhones ?? Enumerable.Empty<AccountAlert>()).ToList();
```

How would I test for and handle a null list if it is going to be the one concatenated onto?

Comment: Can you post how the "xAccountEmails" and "xAccountStuff" are initialized?

Comment: why not just use `new List<AccountAlert>()`

Comment: This is odd: `xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop").ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<AccountAlert>()` -- if xAccountStuff is null, it'll throw an exception calling Where on it. If it's not null, ToList() will always return a list. Do you mean `(xAccountStuff ?? Enumerable.Empty<AccountAlert>()).Where(...)`? Or in C#6, `xAccountStuff.?Where(x => x.prop == "prop").ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<AccountAlert>()` -- note the question mark after ``xAccountStuff.?`.

Comment: `ToList`  will _never_ return null.  If nothing matches the `Where` clause it will return an empty "collection".

Comment: FYI, those are _compiler errors_, not exceptions.  Exceptions happen at _run-time_.

Comment: Oh okay, I see the confusion. I guess I have a deeper issue, `xAccountEmails` and `xAccountPhones` could be the "null" ones, but as @DStanley pointed out, I am not getting null at all, and I do not need to check.

I had abstracted away some logic so I wasn't just looking for `x.prop == "prop"` That's why this all looked like a moot point.

Comment: Now that the confusion is clear, what _exactly_ is your deeper issue?

Comment: That's a whole different issue that deals with half of this stuff is in 3 different tables in 3 different databases. On page load I have to do a bunch of logic that mutates this list, makes calls to different tables, problem is I have to check if some things exist, if not create them, if they do exist, I need to make all 3 tables contain the same information, and then load the primary Email. The reason I thought xAccountEmails is null, is because the first time a user loads the page, Primary Email isn't loading, but on refresh it does. So... yea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToList` will *never* return null. You do not need all of that null checking and converting to list.  If you declare your variables as `IEnumerable<AccountAlert>` you can just do:

```
xAccountEmails = xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop");
xAccountPhones = xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop");

xAccountCombined = xAccountEmails.Concat(xAccountPhones);
```

Comment: what's the difference between calling it IEnumerable<AccountAlert> and having a List of AccountAlerts?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is more general - it could be a list, an array, or a wrapper that enumerates an underlying collection.  It saves you from having to hydrate everything to a specific collection type.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check `xAccountStuff` for `null`, then if you want you can declare `xAccountEmails` and `xAccountEmails` lists when you do the `Where` calls.

Those lists never going to be `null`, maybe empty, but not `null`.

```
xAccountStuff = xAccountStuff ?? new List<AccountAlert>();

var xAccountEmails = xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop1").ToList();
var xAccountPhones = xAccountStuff.Where(x => x.prop == "prop2").ToList();

var xAccountCombined = xAccountEmails.Concat(xAccountPhones).ToList();
```